# Need help extracting JFFS2 filesystem from .img firmware binary

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware

I'm trying to access the filesystem of the EA2750's firmware. Here is a link to download it http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/firmware/FW_EA2750_1.1.7.172380_prod.img. The problem is it is an `img` file and I'm not exactly sure how to go about trying to access it.

Here is the `binwalk` signature scan output:

```
$ binwalk FW_EA2750_1.1.7.172380_prod.img 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x143599, created: 2016-05-04 16:53:12, image size: 1935492 bytes, Data Address: 0x80000000, Entry Point: 0x8000C2F0, data CRC: 0x57C547E2, OS: Linux, CPU: MIPS, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: lzma, image name: "Linksys EA2750 Router"
64            0x40            LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 5956532 bytes
1966080       0x1E0000        JFFS2 filesystem, little endian
```

Comment: I also ran file against it. FW_EA2750_1.1.7.172380_prod.img: u-boot legacy uImage, Linksys EA2750 Router, Linux/MIPS, OS Kernel Image (lzma), 1935492 bytes, Wed May  4 12:53:12 2016, Load Address: 0x80000000, Entry Point: 0x8000C2F0, Header CRC: 0x00143599, Data CRC: 0x57C547E2

Comment: https://blog.bramp.net/post/2012/01/24/hacking-linksys-e4200v2-firmware/ and http://wiki.emacinc.com/wiki/Mounting_JFFS2_Images_on_a_Linux_PC

Comment: I tried running the img file against a programm called jefferson (https://github.com/sviehb/jefferson.git) but when I ran it it gave me this error. Edit: couldn't fit it into one comment.

Comment: File "/usr/local/bin/jefferson", line 498, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/jefferson", line 470, in main
    fs_list = scan_fs(content, cstruct.BIG_ENDIAN, verbose=args.verbose)
  File "/usr/local/bin/jefferson", line 290, in scan_fs
    unknown_node = Jffs2_unknown_node()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cstruct/__init__.py", line 298, in __init__
    self.unpack(string)
  File "/usr/local/bin/jefferson", line 71, in unpack
    cstruct.CStruct.unpack(self, data[:self.size])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: When `file` is run against `1E0000.jffs2` it is recognized as a little-endian `jffs2` filesystem. This means that even though `jefferson` fails to extract it you can mount the jffs2 filesystem, as discussed in both links in my previous comment. To install the mtd tools: `sudo apt-get install mtd-utils`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command `binwalk -Me FW_EA2750_1.1.7.172380_prod.img`

This will recursively extract all files and even extract the JFFS2 filesystem into the folder `_FW_EA2750_1.1.7.172380_prod.img.extracted/jffs2-root/fs_1`

**Edit:** As to your jefferson issue, I believe you need to install cstruct 1.0. So.. https://github.com/sviehb/jefferson/issues/9

Comment: jffs2-root didn't have anything in it but the _40.extracted directory had a file in it called 517834.xz. When I tried to uncompress the xz file it said xz: 517834.xz: Compressed data is corrupt.

Comment: can you md5sum the firmware for me?
`696a94173857c1a2e10d8e72b5bc301f  FW_EA2750_1.1.7.172380_prod.img` also I'm using binwalk version `Binwalk v2.1.2b` . I can host the files for you if need be

Comment: I am using the same version of Binwalk as you (I got it from github yesterday). 696a94173857c1a2e10d8e72b5bc301f  FW_EA2750_1.1.7.172380_prod.img

Comment: Edit: Did you reinstall cstruct using version 1.0 and then try jefferson again?

Comment: I ran sudo apt-get install cstruct but it said the package didn't exist (I'm running Debian 8). Where can I get version 1.0?

Comment: as root: `pip uninstall cstruct && pip install cstruct==1.0`

Comment: I took the liberty to host the files for you on my google drive. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B23Os46TPUJoTWZ0YldoWm84Wms/view?usp=sharing)  `7z x fw.7z`

Comment: Jefferson ran without issue (that I can tell) and it outputted these files JNAP  cgroup  etc     home  libexec  mnt  proc  sbin  tmp  var
bin   dev     etc_ro  lib   linuxrc  opt  root  sys   usr  www

Comment: Those files are also directories. That should be the root filesystem. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Is there a way to extract the filesystem using just binwalk instead of Jefferson?

Comment: Using binwalk with the -e option should extract it but it will not extract the filesystem from the jffs2 image, it will only take the image out of the firmware. The "-Me" option will recursively attempt to extract/decompress everything in the img including everything in the jffs2 image.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help. BTW I heard some researchers found some bugs in the firmware my router is running. How do you think they did that? http://blog.ioactive.com/2017/04/linksys-smart-wi-fi-vulnerabilities.html

Comment: @JohnDoe if his answer and support were useful to you, return the favor by upvoting and accepting his answer

Comment: @JohnDoe this is opinionated.. my best guess is that they studied the cgi files associated with the tool used to control router remotely. They stated "six of (the vulnerabilities) ... can be exploited remotely by unauthenticated attackers". This means that the router by default has a port listening that faces the WAN side of your internet. if you look in the www folder you can study the server-side scripts that your router uses to control the router. If you want to further ask a question I would suggest starting a new thread/question because i'm limited to what i can say in a comment :)

Comment: @JohnDoe Please accept answer if this has satisfied your question :)